# ¿Cómo implementar Method Chaining en un proyecto PHP?

Tags: php, poo

¿Cómo implementar Method Chaining en un proyecto PHP?

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tengo una clase Animal

```
class Animal {}
```

y quiero por ejemplo tener métodos como caminar(), comer() etc de forma tal que se puedan llamar de la siguiente manera.

```
$a = new Animal();
$a->caminar()->comer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes revisar la implementación del **method chaining** a través del siguiente ejemplo

```
<?php

class Heroe
{
    public $name;
    public $power;

    public function callMe($name)
    {
        $this->name= $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function attack($power)
    {
        $this->power = $power;
        return $this;
    }
}

$obj = new Heroe();

print_r($obj->callMe("jorge")
            ->attack("fire storm "));
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Nuestra clase tiene 2 propiedades
- Tenemos 2 métodos, que debes revisar en lo siguiente
- Cada método inicializa el valor de cada propiedad
- Hacemos uso de `return $this` para que el método retorne el valor que esta dentro del contexto de cada método
- Hago la instanciación a través del objeto `$obj`
- Como estoy tendiendo la impresión de un `Object` entonces hago uso de `print_r` y por dentro de dicha instrucción, al objeto `$obj` le indico que acceda de forma continua a 2 métodos, tanto `callMe()` como `attack()`

Answer (score 1):

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es que cada método retorne la misma instancia... algo como:

```
class Animal {
    public function caminar(){
        //lo que quieras hacer
        return $this;
    }
    public function comer(){
        //lo que quieras hacer
        return $this;
    }
}
```